# php xpath query on and xpath result

Tags: xpath

Can I use an xpath query on a result already obtained using xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In most hosting languages/environments (like XSLT, XQuery, DOM) you can**. Don't know about PHP, but it would be strange if it doesn't allow this.

Of course, the result of the first query must be a node-set, in order for a future "/" operator to be possible/allowed/successful on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it in PHP/SimpleXML. The thing that I didn't understand at first is that you're still dealing with the full SimpleXML object, so if you start with "/nodename", you're operating on root. If you start with "nodename" you are starting at the beginning of the result node. Here's my example:

```
$parsed=simplexml_load_string($XML);

$s = '/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item';
$items = $parsed->xpath($s);

foreach($items as $item)
  {
    $s = 'ItemAttributes/Feature';
    $features[]=$item->xpath($s);
    $s = 'ASIN';
    $asins[]=$item->xpath($s);
    $s = 'ImageSets/ImageSet[@Category="primary"]';
    $primary_img_set=$item->xpath($s);
    $s = 'MediumImage/URL';
    $medium_image_url[] = $primary_img_set[0]->xpath($s);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, for example, you can run a query with a context, i.e. a given node. So if you have got a DOMNodeList as a result of the first query you can do things like this:

```
$query1 = '//p';
$query2 = './a'; // do not forget the dot
$node = $xpath->query($query1)->item(0);
$result = $xpath->query($query2, $node);
```

Of course this is a silly example because it could have been done just in one shot with the correct XPath experssion but I believe it illustrates your question.